# Custom field of mobile number is not showing on registration page in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, mobile, registration, custom-field

I want to add mobile no field in registration form.
here is the code

InstallData.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Rouven Alexander Rieker
 * See LICENSE.md bundled with this module for license details.
 */
namespace Semaio\AdvancedLogin\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 *
 * @package Semaio\AdvancedLogin\Setup
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add new customer attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_number',
            [

                'label'                 => 'Customer Number',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'required'              => false,
                'sort_order'            => 10,
                'visible'               => true,
                'system'                => false,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true
            ]
        );


        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'customer_number');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer','checkout_register','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout']);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="customer_number" class="label"><span><?= __('CustomerNumber') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="customer_number" id="customer_number" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomerNumber()) ?>" title="<?= __('CustomerNumber') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

can anyone help me where is the problem?

Comment: Did you check the `customer_number` attribute in `eav_attribute` table?

Comment: yes..it is there. @DineshYadav

Comment: What is the case?
1. Text box is not appearing on frontend.
2. Text box is appearing but value is not being saved in the database.

If it is case 1 then simply try to add an input box in your form. First try to show the text box then go for the customer attribute.

Comment: text box is appearing but value is not being saved in the database.

Comment: I have added my answer. Please remove your current attribute and recreate using the script given in the answer. After that, try to save the value from admin panel in any customer so you will get an idea if your script is working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="customer_number" class="label"><span><?= __('CustomerNumber') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="customer_number" id="customer_number" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomerNumber()) ?>" title="<?= __('CustomerNumber') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign customer group id and attribute set id in your script in order to save the value in your database.

Remove your attribute and recreate it using following script.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Rouven Alexander Rieker
 * See LICENSE.md bundled with this module for license details.
 */
namespace Semaio\AdvancedLogin\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 *
 * @package Semaio\AdvancedLogin\Setup
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        $attributeGroupId = $this->attributeSetFactory->create()->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        // Add new customer attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_number',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Customer Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true
            ]
        );

        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */
        $usedinform[] = "adminhtml_customer";
        $usedinform[] = "checkout_register";
        $usedinform[] = "customer_account_create";
        $usedinform[] = "customer_account_edit";
        $usedinform[] = "adminhtml_checkout";

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "customer_number")
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'used_in_forms' => $usedinform,
        ]);

        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```